# ldap ldif how to add

Tags: ldap, ldif

Having this initialization ldif

```
dn: dc=localhost,dc=localdomain
changetype: add
objectclass: dcObject
objectclass: organization
o: My Example
dc: localhost

dn: cn=Manager,dc=localhost,dc=localdomain
changetype: add
objectclass: organizationalRole
cn: Manager
```

1. How would I add a new organization beneath localdomain?
2. How would I add a new top domain just like "localdomain"?

*The complete LDIFs please.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would add them to the LDIF file (or a separate LDIF file loaded after this one) -- See the [LDIF format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LDAP_Data_Interchange_Format) description for syntax & valid fields for the `Organization` object class.

Adding a new top-level domain is done the same way as any other object, but is administratively a bit more complex: You can do it, but it's "funky" from a view standpoint because it means a new LDAP base (your LDAP tree will have two logical "roots" - `localdomain` & `newdomain`, and you have to be aware which one you're using as the LDAP search base or you'll be in for some confusing results).

If the domains are logically part of the same organization you may want to root your directory at an `Organization` object & put the Domain Components under it (This is a little odd since usually you pick Domain or Organization style structuring, but it's still a valid structure.  Just document the "Why" :-)

Answer (score 0):

Hum...

I think you're working with OpenLDAP, aren't you?

By Organisation, you mean, a new Organisational Unit or a new Top Organisation Container like *.com Organisation container?

Comment: OpenLDAP, yes. Top Organisation Container, not Organisational Unit.